# How to grep AND pattern with pipe

Tags: shell-script, grep, pipe, ps

I wrote a piece of script similar to something below:

```
srvc_location=`ps -ef| grep '${sandbox}.*pset' | head 1 | awk {print $9}`
echo "SERVICE LOC : "$srvc_location
```

But strangely this `$srvc_location` is getting resolved most of the time, but sometimes its not getting resolved with this message:

```
SERVICE LOC : strrosdev_silo1_int.*pset
```

Some additional info:

1. The above piece of code runs in a loop so everytime `$sandbox` has a new value.
2. I tried with  `grep -e "${sandbox}.*pset` 
   but it didn't  solve the issue.
3. I can solve the problem with having two `grep`,  `grep $sandbox |grep pset`,
   but I wanted to use just one with a pattern.

Why is it behaving like this?

Comment: The best method for you to debug this is to save the output from `ps` so you can see input and output, then it should become clear. Just a guess, maybe it finds the grep command from the ps listing and not the sandbox you want ? Find a script that uses `grep`, but avoids finding the searching grep process itself, then incorporate that into your script.

Comment: Welcome to U&L. Please be so polite to read and apply [help→tour](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour). Post her get answered even if you don't put in question irrelevant begging ("Please help me"), so  leave that out of future posts. Including a question, in the post, with a question mark makes it much more clear what you actually want to achieve, but can't.

Answer (score 1):

grep must be greping itself.

you can try

```
srvc_location=$(ps -ef| grep ${sandbox}."*pse[t]" | awk '{print $9;exit;}')
```

- `grep "*pse[t]"` will grep `pset`, but not `pse[t]`

  `pse[t]` as a regular expression (know as RE)  means the string `pse` , then any caracter among `t`, the `[]` syntax is seldom use for one carcater, as it is indeed  easiest to just mention `t`, general use is `grep [abc]oo` who match `aoo`, `boo` and `coo`.

  When you grep **with a fixed string** the result of a `ps`, you also grep the grep process and its arguments.  In the trick above, the RE `pse[t]` evaluate to `pset` and doesn't match the fixed string `pse[t]`.

---

edit: code golf

```
srvc_location=$(ps -ef| grep -m 1 -o ${sandbox}."*pse[t]")
```

- `-m 1` print only one matching pattern
- `-o` only output matchint pattern

Comment: Thax alot !! it seems to work for me.. the code is not failing . But can you clarify what does "grep must be greping itself" mean?  HOW putting [t] makes it overcome the issue?

Answer (score 1):

One reason your code is failing is that you are using single quotes `'...'` instead of double quotes `"..."` in your `grep` expression that surrounds the variable.

Use this instead

```
srvc_location=$(ps -ef| grep "${sandbox}.*pset" | head -1 | awk '{print $9}')
echo "SERVICE LOC : $srvc_location"
```

Actually, there is rarely any need to combine `head`, and `awk` like this, as `awk` can do itself:

```
srvc_location=$(ps -ef| grep "$sandbox.*pset" | awk '{print $9; exit}')
```

or even this, which is less clear but merges in the `grep` too:

```
srvc_location=$(ps -ef| awk -v sb="$sandbox" 'BEGIN { re = sb ".*pset" } $0 ~ re { print $9; exit}')
```

Here we have used several features of `awk`. We define an `awk` variable called `sb` that takes the value of the shell variable `$sandbox`. The `BEGIN` block defines an `awk` variable that contains the pattern we need to match, and the remainder of the scriptlet matches the Regular Expression within the `awk` variable `re` and prints the desired field, exiting immediately it has done so.

Comment: changing  single quote to double quote is giving me the same response....Also just to clarify more, as per what I read on QUOTES... placing double quote will not resolve the value and take it the way it is(as a string), but single quotes resolve it to a variable

Comment: @NishantM please can you provide an example of the value for `$sandbox`. Single quotes treat a string as literals. Double quotes interpolate the value of variables. So if `a="one"`, then `echo "is $a"` and `echo 'is $a'` will print `is one` and `is $a` respectively.

Comment: $sandbox will take value like apsia_silo1_int, apsia_silo2_int, apsia_silo3_int,etc..  To Clarify as exactly what i wish to do... There are many sandboxes in my server and each of this sandbox has many process running under them... through 'ps' i want to take all the process in the server and filter out for individual sandbox's processes as per $sandbox value provided through a loop

Comment: @NishantM so if this code doesn't work for you, what does it do that you don't expect?

Comment: Script does work as expected for almost evertime. But while running in loop sometime it is not able to resolve $srvc_location value. And to my surprise it happens for random value of $sandbox.  So there is something command  with my command srvc_location=`ps -ef| grep '${sandbox}.*pset' | head 1 | awk {print $9}` ... Although as per later answer '${sandbox}.*pse[t]' is solving my problem. But i am still to understand the reason for the failure

Answer (score 0):

The command is better written as

```
srvc_location=$(ps -ef| grep '${sandbox}.*pset' | head 1 | awk {print $9})
```

Your version will set srvc_location to value ps and then tries to execute `-ef` and tries to pipe it's output to `grep` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Just one thing to add to the numerous answers so far:

The command

```
head 1
```

Will output the first *10* lines of the file *named* `1`, and **will totally ignore `stdin`**.

What you want (for that portion of your command) is:

```
head -1
```

which will output the first line (only one line) from stdin.

Or, of course, just use `awk` features as suggested already.  But when you use `head` for anything, you should know this.